# Input::file() returning null Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've been writing an uploading script and even though I'm using the Laravel built in function Input::file() it still returns null. 
I am going to post my Home Controller code.

```
public function handleUpload()
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $username = $user->username;
        $userId = $user->id;
        $path_to_users = "users";
        $user_profile_img = 'users/'.$username.$userId.'/'.$username.'image001.jpg';
        $user_path_profile = "users/$username$userId";
        $user_image_name = $username.'image001.jpg';
        if(file_exists($path_to_users))
        {
            if(file_exists("$user_path_profile")){
                $file = Input::file('profile')->move("$user_path_profile/", $user_image_name);
            } else {
            mkdir("$user_path_profile");
            $file = Input::file('profile')->move("$user_path_profile/", $user_image_name);
        }

        } else {
            mkdir("users");
            mkdir("$user_path_profile");
            $file = Input::file('profile')->move("$user_path_profile/", $user_image_name);
        }
    }
```

When I die(var_dump(Input::file('profile'))) returns null which means it is basically not taking in my file as an actual file. When I do die(var_dump(Input::get('profile'))) it returns the image name meaning that my uploading script is working but the Laravel backend is failing. Is this true, or am I just missing something?

Here is my HTML form stuff:

```
@if($user->id == $userProf->id)

                            <div class="fileUpload button-success pure-button">  
                                <span>Upload</span>
                                <form action="{{action('HomeController@handleUpload')}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input type="file" name="profile" class="upload" />

                                </form>
                            </div>
                            @endif
```

Comment: Can you post your upload form HTML code here?

Comment: I think you use PUT method for upload, Laravel could not handle file request in my experience , use POST method for uploading file.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

I had the same problem in a normal form. I forgot to add:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Answer (score 26):

I had the same issue and realised I had left out something in the form.  Use the built in laravel forms as it will automatically add CRSF protection (see http://laravel.com/docs/html).  Anyway - you need to add `'files' => true` to the top of the form - so for example in the blade template it could look like:

```
{{ Form::open( array('route' => 'admin.store', 'class'=>'form-horizontal', 'files' => true)) }}

{{Form::file('file')}}

{{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

Comment: So easy to forget this! Docs for reference: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#file-input

Comment: I've done this twice now, and this post has saved me twice, thank you @Andrew

Comment: @Andrew could you explain how I might be able to do this in a normal html form? I'm reusing old html and mixing it up with laravel framework and I can't change too much from the code that was already there (jquery is using the form id to create a popup, can I either add an id to laravel generated form or can I add the 'files' => true to a normal html <form> tag?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your code, it should work, so it looks you have a problem in anything else, maybe even your view. I just built two routers to test it here:

```
Route::post('file', function() {

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump(Input::file('profile'));
    echo "</pre>";

});

Route::get('upload', function() {

    return Form::open(array('url' => '/file', 'files' => true)) .
            Form::file('profile') .
            Form::submit('upload');

});
```

You can use them as a baseline to, step-by-step, make yours work too.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enable `file uploads` in your `php.ini` file:

```
file_uploads = On
```

I had the same situation. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and realized I had left something out. Make sure your form is enabled to upload the file. So check that the following attribute is set or not. add CRSF protection. However - you need to add 'files' => true to the top of the form, and make sure again that your  tag contains enctype="multipart/form-data"