# Send file using PUT method Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, laravel

I am using angularjs. I have created a file upload function using angularjs with laravel. The file upload with FormData is working fine. But when I try to send file through PUT method there is no response from the server side.

I have gone through the following answers.
[Uploading a file with jquery and sending as a PUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840972/uploading-a-file-with-jquery-and-sending-as-a-put) and [How to upload a file using an HTTP "PUT" using JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5518420/how-to-upload-a-file-using-an-http-put-using-jquery) but I cannot able to find solution.

Here is my code.

```
<input type="file" ng-file-model = "formData.files" multiple>
```

The directive for my code

```
app.directive('ngFileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.ngFileModel);
        var isMultiple = attrs.multiple;
        var modelSetter = model.assign;
        element.bind('change', function () {
            var values = [];
            angular.forEach(element[0].files, function (item) {
                var value = item;
                values.push(value);
            });
            scope.$apply(function () {
                if (isMultiple) {
                    modelSetter(scope, values);
                } else {
                    modelSetter(scope, values[0]);
                }
            });
        });
      }
    };
}]);
```

Here is my function which converts my form data into FormData

```
constructFormData : function( data ) {
  var fd = new FormData();
  for (var key in data) {
    var value = data[key];
    angular.forEach(data, function (file, i) {
      fd.append('files['+i+']', file);
    });
  }
  return fd;
},
```

Here is my Controller

```
var formData = GeneralService.constructFormData($scope.formData);
FileService.update( formData )
  .success(function( data ){
      if(data.status == 403) {
        $location.path('/403');
      }
      if(data.success) {
          console.log(data);
      } else {
        ValidationService.showValidationErrors(data.errors);
      }
  });
```

Here is my service

```
update : function(formData) {
  return $http({
        method: 'PUT',
        url: $rootScope.baseurl +'/files',
        data: formData,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    });
},
```

The Server side (laravel)

**routes.php**

```
Route::put('/files', ['uses' => 'FilesController@update']);
```

**FilesController**

```
public function update(Request $request) {
  $data = $request->all();
  print_r($data);
}
```

the above `print_r` function displays nothing.

I am get the posted data using `print_r($request->all());`, It gives empty data. I don't know where I make mistake. If I am asking this question by wrong please apologize.

Comment: where is `constructFormData` called?

Comment: What is your backend controller expecting?  Do you have a web method that is expecting `PUT` or `POST`?

Comment: I need to send file using `PUT`

Comment: Does your server have an endpoint expecting `PUT`?  What does that look like?

Comment: We need to see the backend,.

Comment: I have added server side code.

Comment: Where are you specifying method type for the route on server ? You only added the function. IE : https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing Also you should use `return` not `print_r`

Comment: I have added the route.php code also

Comment: So now try `return response()->json($data);` in your function.

Comment: The problem is I cannot able to get the file data. You are given response details. I need to upload file using put method.

Comment: I have tried that too. I am not getting any response. I am getting empty data.

Comment: Hmm, i would take a look into this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22515383/1606432

Comment: Understand my query. Actually when I try to send using `post` method it will works perfect. But I need to send data by `put` method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111441/discussion-between-praveen-srinivasan-and-pogrindis).

Comment: This is a PHP core issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55725521/1072492

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and finally i found this code

```
var formData = new FormData();
angular.forEach($scope.data, function (value, key) {
    formData.set(key, value);
});

$http.post(uploadUrl, formData, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers         : {'Content-Type': undefined}
});
```

Comment: This is using `post` not `put`.

Comment: @Dan you can use put instead of post function, the $http has put method also

Comment: This question is about using `PUT`, which you cannot do, it's a PHP core issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55725521/1072492